# Suspected race problem with jquery.select on a jquery.ajax added element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery-ajax(lets call it #1) function tied to a link that is added by jquery.ajax(call this one #2) itself. The function(#1) tied to the link does fire when added in the document so the funciton(#1) is fine.

The problem seems to be that the jquery.ajax(#1) function tied to the link does not find the link on load and when the link does get loaded via jquery.ajax(#2) its too late.

How can I overcome this?

js

```
$("a[name='searchCatalogue']").click(function(){
        var q = $("#query").val();
        $("#searchResults").html(ajax_load).load("search_data.php", {q:q});
});
$("a[name*='add-']").click(function(){
        var divname = this.name;
        var a = $("#field-"+divname).val();
        $("#materialLista").html(ajax_load).load("handler.php", {fetched_isbn:a});
});
```

added by function(#1) via search_data.php:

```
<input type="text" id="field-add-'.$m.'" value="' . $resultat[$m]["value"] . '" /><a name="add-'.$m.'">Add</a>
```

if the above is added in the document "regularly" (instead of with function(#2) the function(#1) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `live..click` instead of `click`. So you'd have:

```
$("a[name='searchCatalogue']").live("click", function(){
        var q = $("#query").val();
        $("#searchResults").html(ajax_load).load("search_data.php", {q:q});
});
$("a[name*='add-']").live("click", (function(){
        var divname = this.name;
        var a = $("#field-"+divname).val();
        $("#materialLista").html(ajax_load).load("handler.php", {fetched_isbn:a});
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers